# Calculating parallax layer world coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, matrix, 2d

I'm trying to position a sprite in a 2d game at a certain world position on a parallax layer.

So if my parallax layer has a scroll factor of 0.5, when the camera moves 2 pixels, that layer moves 1 pixel.  I'm trying to align trees along the bottom of the maximum extents of the world.

So how do I calculate the position of the sprite I want to place on the parallax layer so that it shows up where I want in the world?  My camera's origin is in the top left if that makes a difference.

I've tried a lot of formulas but no luck and Google isn't being helpful.

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What coordinates do you have and what coordinates do you want?

Comment: wouldn't it just be `worldPosition * scrollFactor`?

Comment: I have the world coordinates I want (height of the level) and I need to know what the screen coordinates that would be on the parallax layer with a certain scrollfactor between 0 and 1 such that when the camera is at: height of the level - camera height, the tree's object position would put it at the height of the level (lined up in rows along the bottom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!  Finally!

For any future searchers:

```
 screen position x = (world position x * scroll factor) +
     (camera width * (1 - scroll factor))

 screen position y = (world position y * scroll factor) +
     (camera height * (1 - scroll factor))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to do this with matrices?